# Snowflake regexp_like breaks when string column contains end of line characters

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We've been pulling our hair out debugging Snowflakes regexp_like/rlike function on a string column. It started silently failing and always returning a False when the string contained a line break (\n).

Example:

```
select regexp_like('looking for a keyword', '.*keyword.*', 'i')
-> True
```

```
select regexp_like('looking for a 
keyword', '.*keyword.*', 'i')
-> False
```

Both expressions, however, should evaluate to True.

Some observations:

1. The ilike function doesn't seem to suffer from this issue.

```
select 'looking for a \n keyword' ilike '%keyword%'
-> True
```

ilike and regexp_like are [differently implemented](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_like.html) which would explain why one works but not the other.

2. The (programmatic) workaround is to strip all linebreak characters.

```
select regexp_like(replace('looking for a 
keyword','\n',''), '.*keyword.*', 'i')
->True
```

We obtained the string entries in our table from websites parsed with beautiful soup. While beautifulsoup removes HTML `<br>` line breaks, it doesn't seem to remove the line breaks encoded through \n and \r. In retrospective, I see that regexp could be tripped up by a newline character.

Is this expected behavior and specific to Snowflake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to provide parameter `s`:

```
select regexp_like('looking for a 
keyword', '.*keyword.*', 'is')
-- TRUE
```

[Specifying the Parameters for the Regular Expression](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#specifying-the-parameters-for-the-regular-expression):

> **s**  -  Enables the POSIX wildcard character . to match \n. By default, wildcard character matching is disabled.

> The default string is simply c, which specifies:
>
> POSIX wildcard character . does not match \n newline characters.

Comment: Wow, I thought I was going crazy. Its a bit strange to me that a line break is NOT matched unless specifically told so.